# How can i add "sub" child to a node with attribute using system.xml

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

i wish you a happy new year!
I got following XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SW.CodeBlock ID="0">
    <SW.CompileUnit ID="1">
        <AttributeList>
            <NetworkSource>
                <FlgNet xmlns="http://www.TEST.com">
                    <Parts> </Parts>
                </FlgNet>
            </NetworkSource>
        </AttributeList>
    </SW.CompileUnit>
    <SW.CompileUnit ID="2">
        <AttributeList>
             <NetworkSource>
                 <FlgNet xmlns="http://www.TEST.COM">
                    <Parts> </Parts>
                 </FlgNet>
             </NetworkSource>
        </AttributeList>
    </SW.CompileUnit>
</SW.CodeBlock>
```

How can i add a Child in "Parts" from SW.CompileUnit ID = 1 and SW.CompileUnit ID = 2 etc.?

I would like to create a loop (for-loop), which creates a child in "Parts" for every "SW.CompileUnit"-Node

Could you please help me?

PS: I use VS2015, C#, not using Linq or XPath etc.

Until now I add a child like this:

```
XmlNode xPiece = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//NS2:Parts",nsmgr);
xPiece.AppendChild(myXMLElement);
```

but it only adds a child in the first SW.CompileUnit Node (with the ID=1)
...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectSingleNode()` returns only the first matched elements. To get all matched elements, you're supposed to use `SelectNodes()` instead :

```
var nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//NS2:Parts",nsmgr);
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    //create new myXMLElement
    ....
    //and then append it to current <Parts>
    node.AppendChild(myXMLElement);
}
```

Btw, parameter of `SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` are XPath expressions (just saying, because you wrote *"I use VS2015, C#, not using Linq or XPath etc"*).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and yeah i think i just missed that part with Xpath ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Linq.  Not sure if I got your request exactly correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                "<SW.CodeBlock ID=\"0\">" +
                    "<SW.CompileUnit ID=\"1\">" +
                        "<AttributeList>" +
                            "<NetworkSource>" +
                                "<FlgNet xmlns=\"http://www.TEST.com\">" +
                                    "<Parts> </Parts>" +
                                "</FlgNet>" +
                            "</NetworkSource>" +
                        "</AttributeList>" +
                    "</SW.CompileUnit>" +
                    "<SW.CompileUnit ID=\"2\">" +
                        "<AttributeList>" +
                             "<NetworkSource>" +
                                 "<FlgNet xmlns=\"http://www.TEST.COM\">" +
                                    "<Parts> </Parts>" +
                                 "</FlgNet>" +
                             "</NetworkSource>" +
                        "</AttributeList>" +
                    "</SW.CompileUnit>" +
                "</SW.CodeBlock>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var compileUnits = doc.Descendants("SW.CompileUnit").Select(x => new {
                ID = (string)x.Attribute("ID"),
                parts = x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "Parts").FirstOrDefault()
            }).ToList();
            foreach (var compileUnit in compileUnits)
            {
                compileUnit.parts.Add(new XElement(compileUnit.parts.Name.Namespace + "ID", compileUnit.ID));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! @har07's solution is fitting better, thank you though

Comment: I wan't sure if you wanted to take the id from the CompileUnit and insert into Parts.  Where is the new ID number coming from?